# clearTimeout() Doesnt work

Tags: javascript

When I double click, it seems that the `clearTimeout(timer)` doesnt work, and the code calls the `function activated(currentactiveid);`

But also the function inside the  `setTimeout("activated2('" + currentactiveid + "')", 2000);` references `timer`. So at the end I think that the problem is that the `clearTimeout` cannot find the variable `timer`.

**HTML:**

```
<td class='td2'  id='currentid1' ondblclick='activatedd(this);' onclick='dclickornot(this);'>Some Text</td>
```

**Javascript:**

```
// Single Click 
function dclickornot(e)
{
    var currentactiveid = e.id;
    var timer = setTimeout("activated2('" + currentactiveid + "')", 2000);
}

// Double Click
function activatedd(e)
{
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var currentactiveid = e.id;
    activated(currentactiveid);
}
```

Comment: Please indent (or at least block) your code...

Comment: Please do not format your code with markup; select it and then use the `{}` to mark it as code for display.

Comment: Even in all the mess of your bad formatted question it is clear that `timer` variable is out of the scope.

Comment: Also, the two `timer` variables are in separate (function) scopes, which means you can't reference them between functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, variables are defined in the scope of the function. So you must use a global variable instead. This still doesn't prevent multiple single clicks, though.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var timer, currentactiveid;

    // Single Click 
    function dclickornot(e) {
        currentactiveid = e.id;
        timer = window.setTimeout(function () {activated2(currentactiveid); }, 2000);
    }

    // Double Click
    function activatedd(e) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = undefined;
        currentactiveid = e.id;
        activated(currentactiveid);
    }
}());
```

Comment: Kudos for doing the function call correctly (by avoiding `eval`). Although I still dislike the global variable.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, yeah, there's not much that can be done about that, though. :)

Comment: @Steve - Are you trying to do something on doubleclick? Note, there is a `dblclick` event handler. See: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#dblclick

Comment: Well, you see I would disagree. See my demonstration: jsfiddle.net/r7wgJ

Comment: Ah, didn't think about that. I updated the code. I'm feeling a little lazy to make a working implementation as there are missing/incorrectly named functions and we don't know what the HTML looks like. But this should give the OP the right idea.

Comment: thank you Tyler and all, I was such a newbie, 4 years later now I am a full stack dev :d

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove 'var' from in front of your timer. It's scope is locked to the dclickornot() function.

Answer (score 0):

Your timer variable is declared inside a function, and is out of scope in the activatedd function. To resolve it, declare timer in global scope, outside the two functions.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the "var" keyword used inside a function creates a local variable that can only be seen from inside this function or from the scope chain created underneath this function.

In your case, "clearTimeout(timer);" is using a timer variable that is always undefined.